# array of object having an another key,value in another object

Tags: javascript

I have a situation where i have array of objects...

```
array[0] = {key:value,key1:value}
array[1] = {key:value,key1:value}
array[2] = {key:value,key1:value}
array[3] = {key:value,key1:value}
```

Now i want to associate array[0] to another array of object `{key,value}` let's take `newArray[0] 's {key,value}`

My `array[0]` has its own set of `key,value` and also points to another object's key,value which it can change.

**Update**:

array[0] having its orginal key,value as well as another key,value from different object... so my `array[0] object has two key,value...`

Comment: You have not managed to convey the nature of your problem at all.

Comment: Is it true that you want to clone the values from newArray and not just create a copy to that both arrays refer?

Comment: @Jens Struwe: I want to create a newArray with my own set of key's and value's which my array[0] would refer... nothing over cloning the object...

Comment: So what's the problem? Just assign it.

Comment: @Ariel: i want both the key,value to persist... instead of pointing one to another...

Comment: @John: So you want to merge another array of key/value pairs into array[0], keeping array[0]'s first key/value pairs in tact?

Comment: @Mike Richards: I don't want that to merge... but to just refer or point alone... this set of array of object's key,value will remain unchanged... but this array[0] will also point another key,value...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an object, the "key" is just a named property, it is not a reference to anything. You can't change the name of a property, all you can do is create a property with a different name, assign the value of the first property to the second, then delete the first one, e.g.

```
function reNameProperty(obj, prop0, prop1) {
  obj[prop1] = obj[prop0];
  delete obj.prop0;
}
```

But there doesn't seem much point to that. What I think you want to do is:

```
var obj0 = {p: 'value};
var arr = [obj0, obj0];
```

So both arr[0] and arr[1] reference the same object. And if one changes:

```
var arr[0] = {q: 'different value');
```

then somehow arr[1] will also reference this new object.

You can only do that if you create a function to do the setting of the value of *arr[0]* and if it somehow knows which other array members should reference the same object.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add a second key.

```
array[0].key2 = object2
```

If I have understood your question correctly.

Comment: @Colin Price: i want this to point to another object's key,value and also have its orginal set of keys...

Comment: I think you need to rethink your object design if you want to have that capability.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean:

```
array[0] = [array[0], newArray[0]]
```

This will make an array of the objects. The old one and the new one.

It's very hard to understand what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want something like this?

```
var arrayA=[];
arrayA[0] = {key:1,keyB:"key3"}

var arrayB=[];
arrayB[0] = {key3:"Hello"}

arrayB[0][arrayA[0]["keyB"]]="Bye";
alert(arrayB[0].key3);
```